# JQuery 3D Gallery (SnowStack) – how do I call images from my server instead of flickr?

Tags: javascript, jquery, gallery

I recently discovered SnowStack, which allows for the creation of a 3D-style gallery, the effect can be seen here http://www.satine.org/research/webkit/snowleopard/snowstack.html

I'm going through the source code now, because I'm trying to find a way of getting it to load images off my server instead of loading random images from Flickr using the Flickr API.

If I had a guess, it's somewhere around here that changes need to be made, but I am a bit of a novice at JavaScrip/JQuery, so would appreciate if someone could help me with the correct way to tweak the code so as to make it load images from a folder on my server instead.

```
function flickr(callback, page)
{
var url = "http://api.flickr.com/services/rest/?method=flickr.interestingness.getList&api_key=60746a125b4a901f2dbb6fc902d9a716&per_page=21&extras=url_o,url_m,url_s&page=" + page + "&format=json&jsoncallback=?";

jQuery.getJSON(url, function(data) 
{
    var images = jQuery.map(data.photos.photo, function (item)
    {
        return {
            thumb: item.url_s,
            zoom: 'http://farm' + item.farm + '.static.flickr.com/' + item.server + '/' + item.id + '_' + item.secret + '.jpg',
            link: 'http://www.flickr.com/photos/' + item.owner + '/' + item.id
        };
    });

    callback(images);
});
}
```

There's also a tiny bit of documentation available, which alas does not seem to operate as suggested: https://code.google.com/p/css-vfx/wiki/SnowStack

Many thanks in advance and feel free to suggest better alternatives to this SnowStack Gallery that you think are better fitted/ more browser-friendly than this!

Comment: Seems like documentation for that plugin is not enough.

Comment: I noticed that too, definitely not enough help. Was trying to make some sense just by reading through the code, but it's quite long...

Comment: @juanpastas – Also found this [https://code.google.com/p/css-vfx/wiki/SnowStack ] ; trying it now but it doesn't seem to work properly!

Answer (score 1):

Your server needs to have url on it that returns a json array with three links for each image, or enough information to construct those three links. You could do this with nodejs, or asp.net mvc, or even a hard-coded response to start with. I'll give a quick explanation about what's going on:

```
var url = "http://api.flickr.com/services/rest/?method=flickr.interestingness.getList&api_key=60746a125b4a901f2dbb6fc902d9a716&per_page=21&extras=url_o,url_m,url_s&page=" + page + "&format=json&jsoncallback=?";
```

This a "RESTful API endpoint" which returns images from flickr (basically a URL that you can call, that tells you about a bunch of images).

```
jQuery.getJSON(url, function(data)
```

Makes an ajax call to get the data from the url. It returns a whole bunch of json, but you'll see further below, that we're only after the `data.photos.photo` items, the data looks something like:

```
"photo":
    [
        {
            "id":"8707154801", 
            "owner":"38142969@N00", 
            "secret":"64b33dfc7b", 
            "server":"8401", 
            "farm":9, 
            "title":"Veyron", 
            "ispublic":1, 
            "isfriend":0, 
            "isfamily":0, 
            "url_m":"http:\/\/farm9.staticflickr.com\/8401\/8707154801_64b33dfc7b.jpg", 
            "height_m":"332", 
            "width_m":"500", 
            "url_s":"http:\/\/farm9.staticflickr.com\/8401\/8707154801_64b33dfc7b_m.jpg", 
            "height_s":"159", 
            "width_s":"240"
        },// ...
    ]
```

The next bit of code consumes an array of these, and you can see that it doesn't use all the fields, just enough to create the links it needs. Your server could just return those links directly if you like.

```
var images = jQuery.map(data.photos.photo, function (item)
{
    return {
        thumb: item.url_s,
        zoom: 'http://farm' + item.farm + '.static.flickr.com/' + item.server + '/' + item.id + '_' + item.secret + '.jpg',
        link: 'http://www.flickr.com/photos/' + item.owner + '/' + item.id
    };
});
```

For each record in the array returned from the url, this code produces a new item, with three urls in it, one for the thumbnail (which you see by default), one for the "zoomed in thumbnail", which it seems you get by hitting space, and one for the link to take you to if you click. The `images` variable ends up being an array of these objects, which is passed to the callback function, which I presume generates the view:

```
    callback(images);
```

So ultimately what you need to do is make a url on your server that returns enough information to construct three urls, and then have a similar function to map your returned data into a list of { thumb, zoom, link } objects. You could just make your server return that data directly, and then you wouldn't need the mapping function.

**EDIT**

Ok, so how would you return this data from a server? I'll use [node](http://nodejs.org) as a quick and dirty example, we'll create a server that simply returns a couple of items that exactly fit the data needed.

```
var http = require('http');
http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
  res.end(JSON.stringify([{
        thumb: "http://example.com/image1_thumb.jpg",
        zoom: "http://example.com/image1_zoom.jpg",
        link: "http://example.com/image1.jpg"
    },
    {
        thumb: "http://example.com/image2_thumb.jpg",
        zoom: "http://example.com/image2_zoom.jpg",
        link: "http://example.com/image2.jpg"
    }]));
}).listen(1337, '127.0.0.1');
```

With this data you could simply use the following code when getting the url:

```
var url = "http://127.0.0.1:1337";
jQuery.getJSON(url, function(data) {
    callback(data);
});
```

Comment: Wow! That's great, makes a lot more sense now. This might sound dumb, but I am a beginner, so – could you please write an example (jsfiddle or even just a link?) to show how to make the server return that data directly? I sort of get what is happening now, but I'm none the wiser as to where to begin....

Comment: @CasperF I've added an example.